# Concurrent grpc calls in java

Tags: concurrency, grpc, peer

I have a dynamic peer to peer network where nodes communicates with grpc. Each node has its own server and client. One grpc method is defined for login of a new Node. I use a sinchronous message to communicate the login to all others, where I create a new channel with each other servers, send a single message and wait a response.

```
rpc enter(LogIn) returns (Response);
```

If I have one node in my network (node 1) and then two or more nodes enter at the same time, for example node 2 and node 3, they'll call both the grpc method "enter" on node1's server. With this type of method, which is the behavior of node1's server? It's able to manage both this request? so with a method like this, grpc queues messages that arrive concurrently or will it handle only one request?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

gRPC supports concurrent execution of multiple RPCs. When an RPC (or RPC event) arrives, it is queued on the `serverBuilder.executor()` specified when building the server. If you don't specify, a default executor is used that uses as many threads as necessary. Nothing in gRPC will behave differently if the RPCs are the same RPC method or different RPC methods.

Comment: Nice! So if I have concurrent thread for concurrent calls on same method, node 1 server is able to reply CONCURRENTLY to node2 and node3, correct?

Comment: Yep! You'd be able to process requests from the other two nodes concurrently.